# How do you read the index in Lucene to do a search?

Tags: java, lucene

Lucene 4.3 Newbie

How do I get a simple search working in Lucene 4.3?

I adapted the outline at in a simple Java test case:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/overview-summary.html#overview_description

The example starts with:

```
DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
```

But DirectoryReader is not visible (protected) according to the docs. So it doesn't seem as if you can use the DirectoryReader.

So I did digging and tried various permutations to avoid direct use of DirectoryReader including:

```
File indexdir = new File("D:\\lucenetest\\") ; // location of my index
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(indexdir);

IndexReader ireader = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(indexdir)); //ERROR NoSuchMethodError
//IndexReader ireader = IndexReader.open(directory); //variation ERROR NoSuchMethodError
IndexSearcher isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
```

Etc. (Including Trying AtomicReaders). Nothing seems to work. (I verified that Lucene Core is properly imported.) The indexing works fine.

I  looked at the Lucene Sample Search Code for more clues. http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/SearchFiles.html

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(index))); //DirectoryReader not visible error
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
```

This also does not work when used in a simple example file.

I have been able to get simple indexing to work and previously was able to get the Lucene demo working (index and search). But, I cannot seem to get a simple search to work.

Any clues?

Comment: Lucene 4.3 API docs say that `org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader` is a public abstract class. Are you sure you are importing the correct class from the correct version of Lucene?

Comment: Thank you Seeta.Stepping away for the night and coming back today, I followed your tip and carefully went through my imports. I use Mahout in this project as well and Mahout seems to depend on Lucene. My Mahout distribution was an older version and apparently uses the 3.6 not 4+ versions of Lucene. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use this code... it's a class that encapsulates all the operations with the LuceneIndex (v4)
It uses near-real-time access to the index so nearly all updates are available to the index reader:

NOTE: It also uses [lombok](http://projectlombok.org)

```java
@Slf4j
public class LuceneIndex {
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  STATUS (ver http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private final IndexWriter _indexWriter;
    private final TrackingIndexWriter _trackingIndexWriter;
    private final NRTManager _searchManager;

    LuceneNRTReopenThread _reopenThread = null;
    private long _reopenToken;  // index update/delete methods returned token

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  CONSTRUCTOR
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Constructor en base a una instancia del tipo responsable de la persistencia del índice de lucene
     */
    public LuceneIndex(final Directory luceneDirectory,
                       final Analyzer analyzer) {
        try {
            // Create the indexWriter
            _indexWriter = new IndexWriter(luceneDirectory,
                                           new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneConstants.VERSION,
                                                                 analyzer));
            _trackingIndexWriter = new NRTManager.TrackingIndexWriter(_indexWriter);
            // Create the SearchManager to exec the search
            _searchManager = new NRTManager(_trackingIndexWriter,
                                            new SearcherFactory(),
                                            true);

            // Open the thread in charge of re-open the index to allow it to see real-time changes
            //      The index is refreshed every 60sc when nobody is waiting 
            //      and every 100 millis whenever is someone waiting (see search method)
            // (see http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NRTManagerReopenThread.html)
            _reopenThread = new LuceneNRTReopenThread(_searchManager,
                                                      60.0,     // when there is nobody waiting
                                                      0.1);     // when there is someone waiting
            _reopenThread.startReopening();

        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
//          if (luceneDirectory instanceof JdbcDirectory) {
//              throw new IllegalStateException("The BBDD table for the lucene index could not be created: " + ioEx.getMessage(),ioEx); 
//          } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Lucene index could not be created: " + ioEx.getMessage());
//          }
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  FINALIZADOR
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        this.close();
        super.finalize();
    }
    /**
     * Closes every index
     */
    public void close() {
        try {
            // stop the index reader re-open thread
            _reopenThread.stopReopening();
            _reopenThread.interrupt();

            // Close the search manager
            _searchManager.close();

            // Close the indexWriter, commiting everithing that's pending
            _indexWriter.commit();
            _indexWriter.close();

        } catch(IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error while closing lucene index: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                             ioEx);
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  REOPEN-THREAD: Thread in charge of re-open the IndexReader to have access to the 
//                 latest IndexWriter changes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private class LuceneNRTReopenThread
          extends NRTManagerReopenThread {

        volatile boolean _finished = false;

        public LuceneNRTReopenThread(final NRTManager manager,
                                     final double targetMaxStaleSec,final double targetMinStaleSec) {
            super(manager, targetMaxStaleSec, targetMinStaleSec);
            this.setName("NRT Reopen Thread");
            this.setPriority(Math.min(Thread.currentThread().getPriority()+2, 
                                      Thread.MAX_PRIORITY));
            this.setDaemon(true);
        }
        public synchronized  void startReopening() {
            _finished = false;
            this.start();
        }
        public synchronized void stopReopening() {
            _finished = true;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!_finished) {
                super.run();
            }
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Index a Lucene document
     * @param doc the document to be indexed
     */
    public void index(final Document doc) { 
        // Indexar en lucene
        try {
            _reopenToken = _trackingIndexWriter.addDocument(doc);
            log.debug("document indexed in lucene");
        } catch(IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error while in Lucene index operation: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                                  ioEx);
        } finally {
            try {
                _indexWriter.commit();
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                log.error("Error while commiting changes to Lucene index: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                                              ioEx);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Updates the index info for a lucene document
     * @param doc the document to be indexed
     */
    public void reIndex(final Term recordIdTerm,
                        final Document doc) {   
        // Indexar en lucene
        try {
            _reopenToken = _trackingIndexWriter.updateDocument(recordIdTerm, 
                                                               doc);
            log.debug("{} document re-indexed in lucene",recordIdTerm.text());
        } catch(IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error in lucene re-indexing operation: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                                  ioEx);
        } finally {
            try {
                _indexWriter.commit();
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                log.error("Error while commiting changes to Lucene index: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                                              ioEx);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Unindex a lucene document
     * @param idTerm term used to locate the document to be unindexed
     *               IMPORTANT! the term must filter only the document and only the document
     *                          otherwise all matching docs will be unindexed
     */
    public void unIndex(final Term idTerm) {
        try {
            _reopenToken = _trackingIndexWriter.deleteDocuments(idTerm);
            log.debug("{}={} term matching records un-indexed from lucene",idTerm.field(),
                                                                           idTerm.text());
        } catch(IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error in un-index lucene operation: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                               ioEx);           
        } finally {
            try {
                _indexWriter.commit(); 
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                log.error("Error while commiting changes to Lucene index: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                                              ioEx);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Delete all lucene index docs
     */
    public void truncate() {
        try {
            _reopenToken = _trackingIndexWriter.deleteAll();
            log.warn("lucene index truncated");
        } catch(IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error truncating lucene index: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                          ioEx);            
        } finally {
            try {
                _indexWriter.commit(); 
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                log.error("Error truncating lucene index: {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                              ioEx);
            }
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  COUNT-SEARCH
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Count the number of results returned by a search against the lucene index
     * @param qry the query
     * @return
     */
    public long count(final Query qry) {
        long outCount = 0;
        try {
            _searchManager.waitForGeneration(_reopenToken);     // wait untill the index is re-opened
            IndexSearcher searcher = _searchManager.acquire();
            try {
                TopDocs docs = searcher.search(qry,0);
                if (docs != null) outCount = docs.totalHits;
                log.debug("count-search executed against lucene index returning {}",outCount);
            } finally {
                _searchManager.release(searcher);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error re-opening the index {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                      ioEx);
        }
        return outCount;
    }
    /**
     * Executes a search query
     * @param qry the query to be executed
     * @param sortFields the search query criteria
     * @param firstResultItemOrder the order number of the first element to be returned
     * @param numberOfResults number of results to be returnee
     * @return a page of search results
     */
    public LucenePageResults search(final Query qry,Set<SortField> sortFields,
                                    final int firstResultItemOrder,final int numberOfResults) {
        LucenePageResults outDocs = null;
        try {
            _searchManager.waitForGeneration(_reopenToken); // wait until the index is re-opened for the last update
            IndexSearcher searcher = _searchManager.acquire();
            try {
                // sort crieteria
                SortField[] theSortFields = null;
                if (CollectionUtils.hasData(sortFields)) theSortFields = CollectionUtils.toArray(sortFields,SortField.class);
                Sort theSort = CollectionUtils.hasData(theSortFields) ? new Sort(theSortFields)
                                                                      : null;
                // number of results to be returned
                int theNumberOfResults = firstResultItemOrder + numberOfResults;

                // Exec the search (if the sort criteria is null, they're not used)
                TopDocs scoredDocs = theSort != null ? searcher.search(qry,
                                                                       theNumberOfResults,
                                                                       theSort)
                                                     : searcher.search(qry,
                                                                       theNumberOfResults);
                log.debug("query {} {} executed against lucene index: returned {} total items, {} in this page",qry.toString(),
                                                                                                                (theSort != null ? theSort.toString() : ""),
                                                                                                                scoredDocs != null ? scoredDocs.totalHits : 0,
                                                                                                                scoredDocs != null ? scoredDocs.scoreDocs.length : 0);
                outDocs = LucenePageResults.create(searcher,
                                                   scoredDocs,
                                                   firstResultItemOrder,numberOfResults);
            } finally {
                _searchManager.release(searcher);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error freeing the searcher {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                      ioEx);
        }
        return outDocs;
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  INDEX MAINTEINANCE
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Mergest the lucene index segments into one
     * (this should NOT be used, only rarely for index mainteinance)
     */
    public void optimize() {
        try {
            _indexWriter.forceMerge(1);
            log.debug("Lucene index merged into one segment");
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            log.error("Error optimizing lucene index {}",ioEx.getMessage(),
                                                         ioEx);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A very simple search can be performed using this sample code

```
// directory where your index is stored
File path = new File(" ... /solr/solr/Collection1/data/index");

Directory index = FSDirectory.open(path);
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

Term t = new Term("myfield", "myvalue");

// Get the top 10 docs
Query query = new TermQuery(t);
TopDocs tops= searcher.search(query, 10);
ScoreDoc[] scoreDoc = tops.scoreDocs;
System.out.println(scoreDoc.length); 
for (ScoreDoc score : scoreDoc){
    System.out.println("DOC " + score.doc + " SCORE " + score.score);
}

// Get the frequency of the term
int freq = reader.docFreq(t);
System.out.println("FREQ " + freq);
`
```

Comment: Thank you. The docfreq is something that I am now using.